# How to select i.i.d samples from the data

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, python, random-variable

While going through maximum liklihood estimator, I have read that "Let $x_1,…,x_n$ be iid samples from $f(x)$". Does it mean, I take out random samples from my population and these are my $x_1,...,x_n$? How do I select $n$? I have done using this:

```
np.random.choice
```

Does this python function generate iid samples? But I really dont know how to select the sample size because if I vary the sample size, my estimated parameters vary and if I keep a constant sample size then run the code second time then my samples change and hence the parameters estimated using distribution models (Beta, Gamma, normal etc.)

Comment: it does generate iid samples, but I doubt this is what you need. can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am using maximum likelihood and method of moment for my image. the pixels are population and I have to work on samples not over the poplulation. I am confused how to select the sample and sample size from my image.